# How can I make the background blur when the popup is active?

Tags: javascript, css

I like to have the background dark or blurred when my popup is active.
The popup must remain unchanged, only the complete background must be dark.
I prefer to have a dark layer added which is in front of the page.
I must work on any website, so when I include this script on any website, it must work.

All code must be made in javascript.
When I close the popup the page must be normal again, like in my code.
Use my code to edit.

```js
window.onload = addElement;



function addElement() {
  // create a new div element 
  // and give it popup content 
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var texts = 'erd';
  newDiv.innerHTML += '<div id="popup" style=" position: absolute;top: 5%;width: 800px;height: 200px;margin: auto;z-index: 99999;display: block;left:25%;background-color: #fff;  border: 1px solid #ddd;  border-radius: 5px;  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 4px #000;  overflow: hidden;   padding: 10px;"><div class="popup_body" style="  height: 160px;">' + texts + '</div><button style="padding: 10px;" class="close_button"onClick="closePopup()">Sluiten</button><button  style="padding: 10px;" class="close_button"onClick="tostoring()">Meer Informatie</button></div>';

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("main_container");
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);

  // open popup onload
  openPopup();
}

function openPopup() {
  var el = document.getElementById('popup');
  el.style.display = 'block';
  var BG = document.createElement("div");
  //BG.style.background-color = 'black';
  BG.style.width = '100%';
  BG.style.height = '100%';
  
 
}

function tostoring() {
window.location.href = '../testing/storing.php';
 
}



function closePopup() {
  var el = document.getElementById('popup');
  el.style.display = 'none';
 
}
```

```html
teefsffstfssgrhhsggsrhservgssfvrhthtrdg rthsgssdsgsssssgegdgssstyygghdeeffsdfsfsdgtrhhfhtrrthsgssdsgsnjissgegdgss
sdrfdsdeeffsdfsfsdgtrhhfhtrrthsgssd

sgsgfksgegdgssjhsssdeeffsdfsfsdgtrhhfhtrrthsgssdsgsstrsgegdgssuiopssdeeffsdfsfsdgtrhhfhtrrthsgssdsgsesrrressgegdgssslkkjsdeeffsdfsfsdgtrhhfhtrvvvtkiyoyuirt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
window.onload = addElement;



function addElement() {
  // create a new div element 
  // and give it popup content 
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var texts = 'erd';
  newDiv.innerHTML += '<div id="popup" style=" position: absolute;top: 5%;width: 800px;height: 200px;margin: auto;z-index: 99999;display: block;left:25%;background-color: #fff;  border: 1px solid #ddd;  border-radius: 5px;  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 4px #000;  overflow: hidden;   padding: 10px;"><div class="popup_body" style="  height: 160px;">' + texts + '</div><button style="padding: 10px;" class="close_button"onClick="closePopup()">Sluiten</button><button  style="padding: 10px;" class="close_button"onClick="tostoring()">Meer Informatie</button></div>';

 // Add The Background cover
  var BG = document.createElement("div");
  //BG.style.background-color = 'black';
  BG.style.width = '100%';
  BG.style.height = '100%';
  BG.style.background = 'black';
  BG.style.position = 'fixed';
  BG.style.top = '0';
  BG.style.left = '0';
  BG.style.opacity = '0.9';
  BG.style.displpay = 'none';
  BG.setAttribute("id", "bgcover");
  
  // add the newly created elements and its content into the DOM 
document.body.appendChild(BG);
document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, BG);
  // open popup onload
  openPopup();
}

function openPopup() {
  var el = document.getElementById('popup');
  var BG = document.getElementById('bgcover');
  el.style.display = 'block';
  BG.style.display = 'block';
  
  
 
}

function tostoring() {
window.location.href = '../testing/storing.php';
 
}



function closePopup() {
  var el = document.getElementById('popup');
  var BG = document.getElementById('bgcover');
  el.style.display = 'none';
  BG.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<body>
  teefsffstfssgrhhsggsrhservgssfvrhthtrdg rthsgssdsgsssssgegdgssstyygghdeeffsdfsfsdgtrhhfhtrrthsgssdsgsnjissgegdgss
sdrfdsdeeffsdfsfsdgtrhhfhtrrthsgssd

sgsgfksgegdgssjhsssdeeffsdfsfsdgtrhhfhtrrthsgssdsgsstrsgegdgssuiopssdeeffsdfsfsdgtrhhfhtrrthsgssdsgsesrrressgegdgssslkkjsdeeffsdfsfsdgtrhhfhtrvvvtkiyoyuirt
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @Guitaro :D

Answer (score 0):

You can lower the background opacity only when the pop is active.

```
Background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
```

Comment: That is nothing, it not helped :(